# Failed to parse SQL query - column invalid identifier

Tags: oracle-apex

I am on Application Express 21.1.0.

I added a column to a db table, and tried to add that column to the Form region based on that table.

I got error...

ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 4, column 15: ORA-00904: "NEEDED_EXAMS": invalid identifier
And I can not find the column in any "source> column" attribute of any page item of that form.

I can query the new column in "SQL COMMANDS".

The new column's name is "NEEDED_EXAMS". It's a varachar2(500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I have many parsing schemas. And I was creating tables through object browser in different schema than my app's parsing schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it manually; use built-in feature by right-clicking the region and then select "Synchronize columns" from the menu as it'll do *everything* for you. It works for reports and forms.

[image]